# пропадает тень у div

Tags: html, css

Вот на скрине тень есть в том случаи если нет элемента под хедером 
http://prntscr.com/nulhpu

а только я боковую панель(фиолетовая справа) приставлю которая сразу идет снизу под блоком справа то выпуклость пропадает. Как сохранить так что б выпуклость осталась и хедер был поверх? z-index. не помогает...

сорри за узкие скрины. Видно вроде норм.

http://prntscr.com/nulhe0

Comment: что-то не могу разобрать Ваш код

Comment: я код не выкладывал...только два скрина...хедер где есть  тень снизу..и хедер где уже нет тени снизу если рядом появисля другой элемент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

добавьте шапке:

```
position:relative;
z-index:2;
```

(ну или выше, чем у нижнего блока z-index, если есть)

без position:relative;z-index:2;

```css
.block {
  height: 15px;
  background: #f0f;
}
.b1 {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.b2 {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block b1">1</div>
<div class="block b2">2</div>
```

с position:relative;z-index:2;

```css
.block {
  height: 15px;
  background: #f0f;
}
.b1 {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  position: relative;
  z-index:2;
}
.b2 {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block b1">1</div>
<div class="block b2">2</div>
```